# Prove a real number in $[0,1]$ has at most two decimal expansions

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove a number $x\in[0,1]$ has at most two decimal expansions. I want to use contradiction but I cannot find one. Can anyone give me a hint or an idea$?$ Thanks.

Comment: Subtraction makes this a problem about zero. Then work in binary to make it easy

Comment: If b={bi} and a={ai} are two different decimal expansions there must be a first j term where bj not equal aj.  wolog bj < aj  Show that *unless* bk = 9 and ak = 0 for all k > j and bj = aj -1, then b < a because bj*10^j < aj*10^j and be 10^j is greater than all further expansion can influence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x = \sum a_i*10^{-i} = \sum b_i*10^{-i}$ where $a_i, b_i$ are single digits 0...9.

Assume $N$ is the first term (if any) where $a_N \ne b_N$ i.e. for all $k < N; a_k = b_k$.  Without loss of generality assume $a_N < b_N$

Then 
\begin{align*}
x & = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} a_i*10^{-i}+ a_N*10^{-N} + \sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty}a_i*10^{-i} \\
& = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} a_i*10^{-i} + b_N*10^{-N}+ \sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty}b_i*10^{-i}
\end{align*}

Now 
$$0 \le \sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty}b_i*10^{-i} \le \sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty}9*10^{-i} \le 10^{-N}$$ and $$0 \le \sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty}a_i*10^{-i} \le \sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty}9*10^{-i} \le 10^{-N}$$

So 
\begin{align*}
x & \le \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} a_i*10^{-i}+ a_N*10^{-N} + \sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty}9*10^{-i} \\
& \le \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} a_i*10^{-i}+ (a_N+1)*10^{-N}+0 \\
& \le \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} a_i*10^{-i}+ b_N*10^{-N} + 0 \\
& \le \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} a_i*10^{-i}+ b_N*10^{-N}+\sum_{i=N+1}^{\infty}b_i*10^{-i} \\
& = x.
\end{align*}

Equality only holds if $a_N = b_N - 1$ and $a_k = 9$ and $b_k = 0$ for all $k > N$. So $x$ has at most 2 decimal expansions.

Comment: Thanks! I see what's going on.